# Wireless connection slow/inconsistent after fresh install Ubuntu 14.04 (Realtek RTL8188EE)

Tags: wireless, 14.04, realtek

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 using the dev builds for a over a month with no issue. Then I upgraded on the official release date and issue started. I got frustrated and did a fresh install and still have same issue.

I can connect to my wireless network just fine, but my connect strength and speed is very sporadic. It seems to oscillate from very slow to normal really quickly like a wave. The ping results below with my router might illustrate this.

Pinging router, normal to low load:

```
    PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.73 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.69 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.71 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=2.10 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=14.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=1.41 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=1.48 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=3.32 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=1.86 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=521 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=1.41 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=1.37 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=1.81 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=1.37 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=5.79 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=28.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=4307 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=3307 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=104 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=1012 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=4.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=1.40 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=1008 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=625 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=5.73 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=22.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=1110 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=519 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=4.82 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=3.03 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=1009 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=44 ttl=64 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=45 ttl=64 time=3.03 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=46 ttl=64 time=1008 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=47 ttl=64 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=48 ttl=64 time=1001 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=49 ttl=64 time=509 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=50 ttl=64 time=1.97 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=1.39 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=502 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 43 received, 17% packet loss, time 51102ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.371/390.573/4307.355/845.151 ms, pipe 5
```

Wireless Info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux kyle-pc 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0181]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa40]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:5606 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2001:f103 D-Link Corp. DUB-H7 7-port USB 2.0 hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:07a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country US:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"HOME-3B12"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search hsd1.wa.comcast.net

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

- Device: wlan0  [HOME-3B12] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8188ee
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           65 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Heather:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2
    13401:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
    nariya:          Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    2WIRE826:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WEP
    belkin.f9c:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
    Heather_VAP:     Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA2
    belkin.f9c.guests: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27
    test:            Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 46 WPA2
    *HOME-3B12:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 66 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.3
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.1

    DNS:             75.75.75.75
    DNS:             75.75.76.76

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### lsmod #####

rtl8188ee              89601  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              626489  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         zhiyuan_yang    <zhiyuan_yang@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     1B8E36556B30AA35325F55D
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008179sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     B6B8AA929B5F982954A6DE1
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     C21FC2F90947540319DE390
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:47:4B:C5:C4:31:20:88:0C:1B:94:A5:39:F4:31
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8179 (rtl8188ee)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[    9.624682] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    9.624741] rtl8188ee 0000:02:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    9.924965] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    9.925132] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   18.918325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   18.918581] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   43.903719] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   43.913895] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   43.915033] wlan0: authenticated
[   43.917383] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   43.932789] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   43.932928] wlan0: associated
[   43.932935] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   59.926537] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[   61.431876] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   61.451881] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   61.453694] wlan0: authenticated
[   61.455569] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   61.469978] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   61.470130] wlan0: associated
[  685.299878] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  686.755325] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  686.764888] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  686.766551] wlan0: authenticated
[  686.770599] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  686.775232] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[  686.775395] wlan0: associated
[  732.676315] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  733.622817] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  733.642409] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  733.644589] wlan0: authenticated
[  733.646068] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  733.660412] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  733.660569] wlan0: associated
[  768.243619] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[  963.122973] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  963.142715] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  963.144191] wlan0: authenticated
[  963.146329] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  963.162557] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[  963.162723] wlan0: associated
[ 1008.407427] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address removed> lost
[ 1010.458107] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1010.477578] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1010.478699] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1010.481203] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1010.495617] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1010.495788] wlan0: associated
[ 1284.910957] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1607.970540] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1607.979974] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1607.982241] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1607.985604] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1607.989180] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[ 1607.989347] wlan0: associated
[ 1641.945884] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1643.299913] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[ 1643.319630] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1643.321682] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1643.323277] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[ 1643.338946] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 1643.339113] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

**EDIT:**

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite S55-A5294.

After upgrading my kernel to 3.14.1 and 3.14.2 (currently using) my wireless is now usable sometimes (which makes me happy).

I lose 0% of packets about 70% of the time and anywhere from 1-100% of packet loss the other 30%.

Reconnecting to my wireless network is the only solution I found so far, but it does not always fix the issue.

/var/log/syslog when issue is occurring

When losing 100% of packets

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog    
May  5 13:05:19 kyle-pc NetworkManager[1107]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May  5 13:05:20 kyle-pc NetworkManager[1107]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
May  5 13:05:20 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:1d:d2:60:3b:10 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May  5 13:05:20 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:1d:d2:60:3b:10 completed [id=0 id_str=]
May  5 13:05:20 kyle-pc NetworkManager[1107]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May  5 13:05:59 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:04:52 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: message repeated 10 times: [ online]
May  5 13:06:11 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: offline
May  5 13:06:31 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: offline
May  5 13:06:56 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: online
May  5 13:08:16 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: message repeated 5 times: [ online]
May  5 13:09:16 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: offline
May  5 13:09:21 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: online
```

When losing anywhere from 1-99% of packets

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
May  5 13:29:48 kyle-pc NetworkManager[1107]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
May  5 13:29:48 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: message repeated 7 times: [ offline]
May  5 13:29:49 kyle-pc whoopsie[1332]: online
May  5 13:29:54 kyle-pc ntpdate[12460]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.012340 sec
May  5 13:30:05 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:30:08 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:30:48 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:30:51 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:31:51 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:33:14 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:33:17 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:34:46 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:36:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: message repeated 2 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
May  5 13:37:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:38:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:39:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:39:46 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:40:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:41:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:42:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:43:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:44:46 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:44:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:45:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
May  5 13:46:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:48:57 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
May  5 13:49:00 kyle-pc wpa_supplicant[12275]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
```

I am unsure if these logs are any indication of the cause of this issue or just a notification that it is occurring.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i've started  bug report for this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1315575

Comment: The answer [here][1] about Larry Finger's new driver worked great for me


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452315/problems-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-on-14-04

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem that I have also been experiencing. To solve it you need to upgrade your kernel manually. I upgraded to 3.14.1 personally.

Here is a guide on upgrading the kernel manually: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

EDIT: I also didn't realise when I posted this, but I have the same wireless card as you, so this should work. I can't guarantee on any other card.

Comment: Tried upgrade to 3.14 and 3.14.1. I receive "Gave up waiting for root device..." then 3 fix suggestions then  ".../dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist". Tried the 3 suggested fix options, but none of them shed any light on the problem. Well I'm confident that the kernel upgrade will probably solve the wifi issue I just have to figure out this boot problem now.

Comment: The kernel upgrade fixed my wifi issue. Thanks. For anyone else I fixed my boot issue using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I also fixed my Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) with this 3.14.1 kernel upgrade on Ubuntu 14.04. No more fluctuating connection and packet loss, thanks!

Comment: I think I spoke to soon when I wrote a kernel upgrade fixed my issue. My ping times are much better, but still lose a lot of packets at times. Not sure if I should un-check the accept this answer.

Comment: If you feel that this answer hasn't helped you then please do remove this as the answer, the whole point of stack exchange is getting useful answers :P It seems that this post has helped at least one person, which I feel good about, and at the same time I was able to solve my own problem. Can I ask, what computer are you using? Maybe we can use that information to find another solution to your problem?

Comment: @CarwynNelson I have edited my original post with more information. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem changing my router to an fixed channel (3 on my case).

I've tried a lot of things like changing my drivers, updating my kernel, but realized that is a lot of wireless networks on my range and this might be conflicting with mine because I had this problem only on one of three networks that I use and on the other two it has no problem.

This was on Ubuntu 14.04 64, notebook dell vostro 5470.

Comment: Upvoted, this works for me.