# problems with Realtek RTL8188ee on 14.04

Tags: wireless, realtek

I am having a wireless issue with my mothers laptop, just installed Ubuntu 14.04 because I'm tired of removing malware from her laptop and now the wireless card wont work.

this is the first time I've ever had  problem with this and I'm not finding anything for 14.04, the card is the Realtek RTL8188ee, the computer is a Toshiba Satellite  C55-A, it works hardwired to my router and with a cheap no name 802.11g dongle I had lying around.

thing is it was connected during the initial installation, but after it rebooted it stopped working and can't figure it out

Comment: "wont work" in what way? Does Ubuntu detect it? Doesn't connect to any network? Connects but there isn't active network?

Comment: [Upgrade kerne](http://chiedi.ubuntu-it.org/questions/18582/wifi-lenta-dopo-linstallazione-di-ubuntu-1404) i have toshiba c50 and RLT8188, i have solved the problem with upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Larry Finger, kernel maintainer, has a github repository with an improved driver. Hopefully it will be merged soon. Until then:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd /path/to/rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

If you're doing this over your current wifi connection and the last step fails, reboot and everything should work.

A brief explanation of the above steps as requested:

1. Use `sudo apt-get` to install what is nessesary to build the
   driver.
2. Use `git` to clone the github repository. See `man git` for
   more info.
3. Use `cd` to change directory to wherever you cloned the
   repository to. You'll need to be in that directory to build it. For
   example: `cd ~/stuff/rtlwifi_new` in my case.
4. Use `make` to build the driver.
5. Use `sudo modprobe -rv` to unload the current driver.
6. Use `sudo make install` to install the new driver.
7. Use `sudo modprobe -v` to load the new driver.

Comment: Can you please explain at least roughly what these commands do? (see [How to write good answers](/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: Is the github repo public? Do you have a link?

Comment: `make -j4` where 4 is the number of cores, should speed up the build a bit, right?

Comment: This improved my wifi speed by about 5-10x after installation.  Unfortunately, it's still not to par compared with other wifi devices which are about 2x faster.  The driver by FreedomBen works for my RTL8188EE, but poorly.

Comment: This fixed the random wifi disconnects in my Asus X550VX laptop with `rtl8821ae` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the correct drivers worked for me with most wifi networks.  One particular network remains intransigent but all others are fine.  Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r firmware/* /lib/firmware
```