# Need help with wireless driver for Lenovo E545 (Realtek RLT8188ee

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

I am having trouble with getting my wifi to work. I installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 (Its really weird, I choose UEFI mode to go into windows and legacy mode to go into Ubuntu 12.04). Anyhow the only internet that I can get is a wired internet connection and my home wifi (I added that when installing). There is no wifi icon in the top bar but I am connected to our home wifi because I can load webpages. The driver I would need is Realtek RLT8188ee, which has no linux variation available. I tried this guide here [Wireless not working on Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281) .

Every thing was fine until I ran the `make` and `sudo make install` commands. Errors are here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhXC2.png (red is `make` blue is `sudo make install`, these were the only errors I saw).

In case anyone cares I ran `uname -mr` in terminal and this came out `3.13.0-41-generic x86_64`

I also ran the final command `sudo modprobe rlt8188ee` and it just returned to a command line, like what happens when a command is done, so i assumed that worked or depended on the previous commands to work.

So what do I do? How do I fix the driver? I'm not the most advanced in Ubuntu so if you could break things down a little more, or even explain what it does that would be great.

Oh and this is AMD architecture

As asked by chili555 I ran those commands and pasted the results here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9503274/  The first block was the first command and so on and so forth.

---

Thought I'd give an update: The wifi is now working after I ran updates and restarted. I still cannot see wifi options and status in the top bar, but i can see it in settings->network.

Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Although the link you gave asks that you compile backports-3.11, you compiled the much older and incompatible backports-3.2. In fact, rtl8188ee is included in Ubuntu 14.04, which uses kernel 3.13, by default! There is no need to compile anything:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ modinfo rtl8188ee
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
```

Please give us some diagnostics so we may see what is going wrong:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
rfkill list all
dmesg | grep rtl
```

As the results may be lengthy, please paste them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com. I will then edit this answer to propose a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the driver was working better a few releases ago, so the backport driver was not that bad of a suggestion.  I tried it, and it worked better than the one in the 3.13.0-32 kernel. However, the new driver that Larry Finger has seems to work far better than either one.  You can find directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452315/problems-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-on-14-04)