# Trying to install Ubuntu on a HP 15 Notebook?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, acpi

I am trying to install Linux on a HP Notebook 15-ba026ns model on a separate partition to Windows 10.

I have disabled Secure Boot and am trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu through USB. When I attempt to boot Ubuntu via USB, I get the following error messages:

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLTxx.jpg)

My processor is AMD and Radeon graphics is being used. Also, the loading screen for Ubuntu freezes upon start up, and when I tried to install Linux Mint previously there were issues with GRUB not loading.

As per the above error, does ACPI need to be turned off? Is there any risk of damage to the Windows partition by doing this?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Errors are not legible :/

Comment: Apologies, was the best I could get. However, I'm getting a load of ACPI errors as mentioned.

Comment: You may need boot parameters like *nomodeset* and/or *acpi=off*.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned, is there any risk of damage to Windows from doing this?

Comment: No, those are parameters of the Linux kernel and won't affect Windows in any way.

Comment: @david --  this has nothing to do with black screen. it is the ACPI errors that now show with 4+ kernels. there is no problem with booting other than the annoying flash of errors

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same laptop. These are namespace look up errors. Kernels earlier than 4.0 hid these errors.

It is one message per CPU. In the code for ACPI, they have this particular namespace written twice once in uppercase and once in lower case so one of the two errors.

They can be ignored. Leave ACPI on.

The default drivers for the Realtek wifi will not work. You need to get these from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry because I'm new to working with Linux on a HP, but how would I go about installing these?

Comment: you will have to do it after you have installed via the eithernet connection which works fine. directions are here  https://askubuntu.com/a/543765/694267. one change has to be made. with the newer kernels driver modules have to be signed if secure boot is on so do `make dkms` instead of `make install`