# Ubuntu 16.04 connected to WIFI but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, hp

There are like 20 questions like this, but none of these helped me to resolve this issue.

I can access Internet using cable and i can connect to my wifi network but when i try to load a website or ping google.com the request fails.

it happens using Ubuntu from USB too.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you so much.

Edit: Fixed updating driver. [problems with Realtek RTL8188ee on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452315/problems-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-on-14-04?rq=1)

Comment: What do you mean by "Edit: Fixed updating driver. problems with Realtek RTL8188ee on 14.04"? Is your host resolution problem fixed? What is "fixed"?

Comment: The problem is fixed updating my Realtek RTL8188ee drivers as commented on the question i linked.