# Massive download speed reduction after fresh 14.04 install on dual boot Mac

Tags: networking, dual-boot, macosx

After a weekend of pouring through how-to's, I have successfully installed and booted Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (x64) along side Mac OS X Mountain Lion, on my Macbook Pro. It was a small victory.

For the most-part, it's smooth-sailing. However, I have noticed a drastic decrease in my WiFi speeds **both while booted in Ubuntu and on OS X**. Compare 0.4Mbps to 24Mbps download speed on a Windows machine on the same network.

Does anyone have any advice on how to remedy this?

A few details on my install procedure:

- Mac Disk Utility to partition my SSD
- [rEFind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) boot manager
- Install from DVD burnt by following Ubuntu's [How To burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)

*Edit:* I did read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451724/wireless-connection-slow-inconsistent-after-fresh-install-ubuntu-14-04-realtek) about slow wireless connections on 14.04; however the accepted answer here is a kernal upgrade. As my problem is occurring on both the OS X side and the Ubuntu side, I don't see these issues having a common cause

*Edit2*:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller (rev 08)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Thanks if you can point me in the right direction, or have found a solution for this

Comment: I don't think I'd call it a minor victory...  There are a number of suggestions for improving network connectivity on Ubuntu which are all dependant upon the hardware - since I'm not a Mac guy, I'm afraid I won't be much help.  http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ had a number of useful tips - the only one I currently use is the nsswitch modification.

Comment: Check with e.g. lspci for you WiFi hardware and than we might could help you a little

Comment: @frlan added. Also, I just switched to the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA and it seems to have helped a little bit